# AndEngine - тень для спрайта

Tags: java, android, andengine

Приветствую знатоков Android и AndEngine!
Вопрос следующий - имеется ли возможность в andengine задать тень для спрайта?
Есть спрайт с текстурой стола неправильной формы. Нужно что-бы стол отбрасывал тень. Один из вариантов - сделать еще один спрайт с тенью и подложить его под мой спрайт. Но такой вариант мне кажется не оптимальным.

Вот изображение того что есть и того что нужно:
[image: слева стол, справа нужная тень]

Буду благодарен за любые ответы. Или обоснование того, что отдельная картинка- тень все-таки выгоднее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В большинстве случаев создается спрайт с уже готовой тенью и применяется где надо. Насчет "оптимальности", скорость является главным фактором в играх, тем более не на десктопе. Рисовать готовый спрайт будет побыстрее, чем вычислять оффсеты теней спрайтов, а затем еще накладывать блюр.

Тут очень хорошее объяснение - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20478/what-rendering-techniques-would-i-use-to-draw-a-drop-shadow-effect-for-cards-in

Comment: Да, спасибо за ссылку. очень интересно. Действительно - спрайтом будет побыстрее.